# Insert link with Konva React

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I want to to make linkable shapes / images on the canvas.

```
<Stage>
  <Layer>
    <a href="somewhere">
      <Circle/>
```

Something like this. ^

I didn't find anything in the docs, so maybe some of you found a way around and accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

```
<Label x={350} y={350}
                       onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnterHandler}
                       onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeaveHandler}
                       onClick={(e)=>window.location="https://www.google.com"}
                       className={this.state.zoom ? 'zoom' : ''}

                >
```

The label tag supports mouse Enter/Leave/Click events, and I used handlers for those.

```
onMouseEnterHandler=(e)=>{
    console.log(e)
    e.target.fill('blue');
    this.stageRef.draw();
    this.setState({
        hovered:true,
        zoom:true
    })
}
onMouseLeaveHandler=(e)=>{
    e.target.fill('white');
    this.stageRef.draw();
    this.setState({
        hovered:false,
        zoom:false
    })
};
```

After handling your events, you might have noticed I used         `this.stageRef.draw();` to rerender the changes on the canvas.
stageRef is a reference of the stage (obviously), and you can get one like this

```
        <Stage
            className={this.state.hovered ? 'special' : ''}
            ref={node=>this.stageRef = node}
        >
```

You can make the label more interactive by adding dynamically increasing font size on hover, changing font color, changing cursor etc..